# What is the name of that matrix norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

I am interested in the following matrix norm: if $A = [{\mathbf a}_1, \cdots, {\mathbf a}_n], {\mathbf a}_i\in {\mathbb R}^m$, then
$$
||A|| = \max_{|x_i|\leq 1, i\in [n]} \sigma_1([x_1{\mathbf a}_1, \cdots, x_n{\mathbf a}_n])
$$
where $\sigma_1$ is the largest singular value.
Is there any name for that norm?

Comment: Is norm the just multiplying $\sigma_1$ by the absolute value of the largest column vector? What’s the context, where did you find this norm

Comment: I just need to bound $||A{\rm diag}({\mathbf x})||$, but the bound 
$$
||A{\rm diag}({\mathbf x})||\leq ||A|| \cdot \max_{i}|x_i|
$$
is not sufficient for me.

Comment: @qwerty43 Without more information about $A$, this is the best bound that can be given.

Comment: $A=[{\mathbf e}_{1},...,{\mathbf e}_{d}, S{\mathbf e}_{d+1},...,S{\mathbf e}_{n}]$ where $\{{\mathbf e}_{i}\}$ is a standard basis, and $S$ is PSD, $||S||\leq 1$.

Comment: @qwerty43 It is easy to see that in the case of $S = 0$, no better bound is possible.